# creating and destroying shieldUI widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, shieldui

I am coming from a different development background with a very little jQuery and/or shieldUI knowledge. Can someone please very shortly explain how to remove/destroy shieldUI components or widgets? I don't see any special widget method therefore I assume this is done with jQuery. By destroying I mean removing everything down to (including) markup.

Also, what happenes with widget when calling hide()? I see that markup is somehow stripped down (removed), but some wrappers remain. Is it safe to call another widget setup with the same "id" ? will it overwrite? will it cause object orhpans?

As you see I am missing some very basic "how it works". I am a quick learner so please, just few basic pointers will do. Thank you :)

EDIT: found destroy widget method under "swidget()"...what is swidget?

Comment: .swidget() is giving u access to the object so u can access his properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swidget()` gives you a reference to the component instance, through which you can access methods and properties, such as `height`, `width`, `refresh()`, `destroy()`, etc.

Further, with respect to the question at hand, regarding the destroy method and approach - the ideas is, that whenever you need to refresh some data on the component, you can recreate it, rather than calling a method such as rebind. 
This is demonstrated in the following demo:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/rangebar-chart/related-charts

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I have some basic idea how it works. I will set up a test project to see how it handles. In all demos I see that basic html elements are already declared up front. Is this a preferred way of setting up a layout or such, or it makes no difference if elements are dynamically created from code during execution when required?

Comment: It should not make any difference, as long as you initialize the Shield UI widget after the HTML element has been added to the DOM.